# Local testing WP theme in IE8 gives a strange layout?

Tags: wordpress, cross-browser

Trying to test my theme on IE8 locally gives a bad result. But on the testing server it looks much better (not yet the same as FF or Chrome).

What do i need to do so my local IE8 behaves the same as IE8 on the server??

I am trying to get the full-screen background in IE8 to work with transparent div's

Bit clueless here.

regards

oh i use xampp for windows

Comment: if you will not post a link to the server , it will be hard to target .

Answer (score 1):

Without a link or code, all I can say is be sure your code is W3C valid. Missing and out of place tags are leading causes of bad IE display in Wordpress. Use the W3C Validator either live at http://validator.w3.org/ or as a local standalone http://habilis.net/validator-sac/

Comment: hi tx for your answer. My theme validated ok. Should have given more info, for example i am testing locally localhost. And it seems that IE browser on localhost doesn't see `<!--[if lte IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesIE.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->` going to do a search on css and IE conditional statement